# Client connect Server via Http proxy server(Windows c\c++)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, http-proxy

We have a C\S model program. And users use client to connect our server. But some company users surf the Internet via HTTP proxy Server(not SOCKS4 or SOCKS5 proxy server). In this case, we need provide a feature to set the client proxy server（just like some other software）. If do so, we should package our original data to Http protocol. So I want to know:

1. Is the method OK? Or there are some other better method to solve the problem.
2. If do so, Can our server send data to client initiatively?
3. Do you know other released software which have the feature to set proxy server how to deal this problem?

Answer (score 2):

That is not how HTTP proxies work.  You do not have to re-package your existing data as HTTP.  All you need to do is:

1. connect to the HTTP proxy port, and send it an HTTP `CONNECT` request specifying the host/IP and port to connect to, eg:

   ```
   CONNECT hostname:port HTTP/1.0
   User-agent: MyApp
   ```

   If the proxy requires authentication, you can also provide a `Proxy-authorization` header containing the encoded credentials as needed, eg:

   ```
   CONNECT hostname:port HTTP/1.0
   User-agent: MyApp
   Proxy-authorization: basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0
   ```
2. if the proxy accepts the request and is successful in connecting to the requested host, it will send back an HTTP `200` reply, eg:

   ```
   HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
   Proxy-agent: ProxyApp/1.1
   ```
3. you can now send and receive your data as you were already doing before, and the proxy will pass the data as-is between the client the host in both directions.  You do not have to change any code logic other than to establish the proxy connection.

See [Tunneling TCP based protocols through Web proxy servers](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01.txt)
 for more details.

This process is similar to the way other proxy protocols work, like SOCKS.  The client connects to the proxy, requests a connection to the server host, and then the client and server pass data back and forth as if the proxy were not present.

Comment: Dear Remy Lebeau,thank you very much for your help.But there are another problem. Most HTTP proxy server only use "CONNECT" to  connect destination from the port 443.So if use the method,the data " hostname:port HTTP/1.0" must be " hostname:443 HTTP/1.0" But our client connect server from three  channels,that is ,our server listen on three port(E.g. 1234,1235,1236),our client need to connect these three.So the method is not OK.Do you know any other method to deal with this problem or other software how to deal with proxy server? Thank you very much!

Comment: `CONNECT` is not limited to port 443, it works for any port. `CONNECT` is commonly used for SSL tunnels, but is not limited to that. And HTTPS is not limited to port 443, either. So any proxy that does not support `CONNECT` for ports other than 443 is not a worthwhile proxy to use.

Comment: And `CONNECT` is how HTTP proxies support non-HTTP protocols. HTTP proxies also support absolute URLs (w/ host and port) for `GET` and `POST` requests, but that only applies to actual HTTP-based protocols.

Comment: And don't forget about "\r\n\r\n" after the header section.